# What is it that automatically checks configuration changes (such as those in /etc) into Git?

Tags: git, safari, version-control

I remember reading on the Ubuntu forums some time ago about a program to automatically check configuration changes into version control for you.  It was (of course) not Ubuntu-specific.  I'm pretty sure it used [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), though it may have been [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), or perhaps even able to work with multiple different [VCSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).  My googling has turned up nothing, and I'd rather not roll my own script if someone has already done this well.

Of course I could just manually check things in, but there are reasons I'd like it done automatically.  (I'm actually planning to use this for my LastSession.plist file for [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), so when the #@$%^*&! thing crashes, and I don't restore everything, and then [Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) crashes, the fact that it has such lousy session management won't mean I lose the dozens of windows with dozens of tabs I had open.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a lot of them. Personally, I use [etckeeper](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Can you tell me more about why you prefer etckeeper vs other options? I've only read a little bit about the different possibilities, but I did notice that git can cause problems if it runs into hardlinks...i see etckeeper allows you to choose from different places to host your repo (git, mercurial, darcs, bzr), which one do you use?