# Which version control should I use for my configuration files?

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I want to store some of my configuration files (~/.emacs.d/, .Xdefaults, etc. linux $HOME stuff) in version control so I can easily sync them with my notebook/workplace and see my past changes and revert to them should the need arise.

So far it seems to me that there are quite some people using git for this and I think that I too want to use a distributed vcs for this (if only to get more used to them) but I can't say that I am very experienced with all things dvcs. I did use darcs and git briefly and so far I can say that I really like the way git handles branches, and I think the possibility to have different branches within the same directory is especially useful for my use case. Darcs on the other hand has cherry picking of patches, which too is quite the convenient feature when managing configuration files (at least I assume it is).

So, what would you recommend to use? And what would be your reasoning for your recommendation? What other vcs with nice feature that I haven't mentioned exist and would make a good vcs to store configuration files and why?

Comment: questions about doing this with git: http://superuser.com/questions/132393/how-to-track-home-with-git .. http://superuser.com/questions/130269/what-is-it-that-automatically-checks-config-changes-such-as-those-in-etc-into

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it yet but am thinking about doing something like this using [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) which is a single executable DVCS that also has a built-in wiki and uses sqlite for storage.

Answer (score 1):

anything NOT centralized, probably. I;d think git, though